# R.java not generated in eclipse

Tags: android

[image: R.java not generated]

[image]

R.java is not generated. I tried several strategies like cleaning and building etc, none of them seemed to work. Please dont mark this as duplicate since I have tried all the strategies that has been told in other questions.

Comment: goto andorid sdk manager and make sure you have installed android sdk build tools if you have updated adt to rev 22. Clean and build the project.

Comment: see ur xml file some tag or other thing wrong on it have u check???

Comment: I have nothing wrong with my XML(as they are all auto generated)

Comment: @Raghunandan Please see the edits,I have added a pic of the sdk manager.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat Android sdk build tools is not installed. install the same. Clean and build the project

Comment: @Raghunandan.. that worked thanks.
If you could add that as answer I could do an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem with not generating the R file is that you have an error somewhere in your code. Something doesn't match, isn't imported, etc. The R file isn't built until your code can be compiled without errors, even though sometimes it does anyway. I can't give you a reason why it does that, but make sure you don't have errors.

Comment: All the files are auto generated,I havent made any edit in any file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the bottom of your eclipse view and look for a tab that says "Console". It may just show you that youve declared something in one of your layouts that doesnt make sense to the compiler or something like that. Also check the error log and the problems tab.

Comment: try checking what version of java your project is using. Sometimes eclipse is using the wrong version. If its set to 1.4 or 1.5 change it to 1.6 or 1.7 you can do that by navigating through the project settings

Comment: thanks for your time. please see the comments,I had not installed the android sdk build tools.